# Where does glCopyTexImage2D save its pixels to?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

```
Name
glCopyTexImage2D — copy pixels into a 2D texture image

C Specification
void glCopyTexImage2D(GLenum  target,  GLint  level,  GLenum  internalformat,  GLint  x,  GLint  y,  GLsizei  width,  GLsizei  height,  GLint  border);
```

Apparently, the pixels must be stored somewhere, but where? The function returns void and does not use a pointer parameter.

SO, where does glCopyTexImage2D save its pixels to?

Comment: -1: For asking a question that is easily answered *within your own question*.

Comment: @Nicol, the openGL manual for [glCopyTexImage2D] (http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCopyTexImage2D.xml) did not say anything about glGetTexImage, while the docs for [glGetTexImage] (http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetTexImage.xml) relates its usage with glCopyTexImage2D. Instead of being a helpful user like the ones below who shed light on my doubts, you down-vote my question with a vague reason. These are the exact kind of replies teachers give when they don't know the answer to a question but can't lose to lose face.

Comment: @Nicol, furthermore, this question has an opengl-es tag to it, which makes my problem in hand more complicated because ES doesn't support glGetTexImage. As a "game developer with a fairly broad knowledgebase in the fields of animation and graphics", you sure missed my point by a long shot...

Comment: `glCopyTexImage2D` has nothing to do with `glGetTexImage` at all. The latter is for getting texel data into your application from a texture; the former is for creating a texture from the framebuffer. So the operation of `glCopyTexImage2D` has *nothing* to do with `glGetTexImage`. And I have no idea why you brought it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Into a texture you specify as `target` (e.g. `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, which would mean currently bound 2D texture). After using that you can use `glGetTexImage` to fetch the pixels from the texture to your own buffer.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for! Must the corresponding parameters match?

Answer (score 4):

First line of the man page:

> glCopyTexImage2D defines a two-dimensional texture image, or cube-map texture image
>               with pixels from the current
>               GL_READ_BUFFER.

It copies pixels from the read buffer to the actively bound texture.

Comment: You mean [this man page](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCopyTexImage2D.xml)